# Define alias for a directory as an argument to cd in Bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, alias, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Windows 10 Linux Subsystem (Ubuntu Bash).

I want to access my Windows folder from Ubuntu Bash.

The folder I want to access is (note that there are spaces in the names):

```
/mnt/c/Users/some folder1/some folder2/destination - folder/
```

What I do now in Bash is:

```
~$ cd /mnt/c/Users/some\ folder1/some\ folder2/destination\ -\ folder/
```

Because the directory is too deep, I don't want to type the long command every time. So I want to define an alias for that folder.

In Bash, I created a file `~/.bash_aliases`. And in the file `~/.bashrc` there is following command:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Next, I want to add the following line in `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
alias mf=<the correct format of the directory>
```

After `mf` is defined, I want to switch to the directory using the following command:

```
~$ cd mf
```

Can you help me with this?

1) How do write the `<the correct format of the directory>`?

2) What else do I need to do in order to use

```
~$ cd mf
```

Comment: I wanted the same functionality so I made a simple CLI that creates a `cdd` terminal command which works almost like `cd` but helps create aliases to any path on the go. Hope it helps :) https://github.com/nsrCodes/cdd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [this page](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html) notes, "an alias is only meaningful at the beginning of a command". So your alias can't be an argument to cd. What you *can* do is

```
alias cdmf='cd /mnt/c/Users/some\ folder1/some\ folder2/destination\ -\ folder/'
```

i.e. including the `cd` command in your alias, so that typing 'cdmf' takes you to your target directory.

To use `cd mf`, you'd normally use a symbolic link (or a bash function), not an alias. Try

```
ln -s /mnt/c/Users/some\ folder1/some\ folder2/destination\ -\ folder/ mf
```

However, the link that this produces only resides in the current directory, so you can't navigate to your target directory from anywhere.

Comment: Yep symlinks are the way to go. I'd generally put such symlinks in `~` (e.g. `ln -s ... ~/mf`) so that you can do `cd ~/mf` from anywhere.

Answer (score 11):

Rather than alias, you can use the `cdable_vars` option available in bash (documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html)). To enable, add `shopt -s cdable_vars` to your .bashrc and then create an environment variable that contains the directory path. For example, you might add this to your .bashrc

```
shopt -s cdable_vars
mydir=/really/long/dir/path
```

and then you will be able to use this in the shell as follows:

```
mike:/home/mike$ cd mydir
/really/long/dir/path
mike:/really/long/dir/path$
```

Comment: works great if you have like Documents on another drive but still want to use cd Documents (also remapped it in nautilus)

Comment: Just wanted to add that BOTH lines need to go in the `.bashrc` as the shopt status doesn't retain between sessions.